# Upgrade site collections inside my online central administration

Tags: sharepoint-online, central-administration, upgrade

I am working on an Office 365 sharepoint online server. and inside the SP admin center . i found an option to Upgrade site collection/s:-

[image]

First question. now i am not sure what do Upgrade exactly do ? now when i use to work on SP on-primes, the upgrade is done to the whole farm at once and not to selected site collections..

so does this mean that inside Office 365 i can upgrade certain site collections and leave the other on older versions ?

Second question. is the upgrade similar to running the SharePoint product configuration wizard as in on-premise SP ?

Third question. can I know the current build number for the site collection ? and the build number i will get after the upgrade ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It upgrades the site collection like when you went from 2010 to 2013 and could then flip the UI over to 2013.

No.

It can be found via `https://tenant.sharepoint.com/_vti_pvt/service.cnf`

```
vti_encoding:SR|utf8-nl
vti_extenderversion:SR|16.0.0.5903
```

http://modery.net/whats-my-sharepoint-online-version/

Comment: thanks for the reply. so now let say Office 365 provide a new feature for sharepoint, then will i get this feature directly to my site collection or i need to upgrade it manually ? second question . now inside the on-premise SP i have never upgrade the site collection , as i was on 2013 from the beginning .. so not sure if the upgrade site collection option inside on-premise have a similar functionality as in office 365, or both upgrade options have different meaning inside on-primise compared to office 365 ??

Comment: Updates are released in rings based on your tenant settings. If you are a first release you see updates first, otherwise you get them when they roll out to the general availability ring, they just show up when they are deployed to your tenant.

Comment: so in this case the Upgrade site collection option inside SP online is used to apply new features/updates to the site collection, while the upgrade site collection option inside SP on-primise have different meaning and it is used to upgrade the site collections from 2010 to 2013 is this correct? this what lead me to get confused , as i worked on many on-premise 2013 SP , and this is my first SP online project,, so i was trying to understand the differences between on-primse site collection upgrade and between online site collection upgrade options.. seems they are totally different.

Comment: can you please adivce on my above comment if possible ?thanks